# Communicating between Google Calendar, Google Forms and Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

Consider a Google Calendar scenario with various rooms that can be booked. Users will be browsing the different rooms and can create an entry in one of the free slots. The basic default properties provided by the Google Calendar are not sufficient for the business scenario but I haven't found a way to add more fields: the default new event form does seem to be customisable. Is this so?

My idea was to provide a Google Form to cover the rest of the details.

The process would look as below:

1. The user browses the different rooms and finds an available slot. The calendar entry is created with the basic details. The entry is added into the calendar and the details are recorded into a Google spreadsheet.
2. The user receives an email with another google form: the ID of the appointment would need to somehow be passed as parameter. The google form will be used to insert the "advanced details" into the spreadsheet.
3. An interface will be created to view the spreadsheet data in a more structured and user friendly manner.

Can something like this be done using Google Calendars, Google Forms and App Script? Any pointers where to start from? Or if not, how the process could be changed to be actually possible. The only starting points I found were Add ins which create calendar entries directly from Google forms, but this would require the user to start from a form, rather from the calendar, which I would not rather go for, not at least until I know there's no other way.

Comment: I think you should look into service accounts https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script

Comment: would this be a service that runs every x minutes, and do the required logic to communicate between the calendar and the sheet, as well as as send any required emails?

Comment: Is this not already natively possible? https://support.google.com/a/answer/1686462?hl=en

Comment: Calender is the only App I haven't worked with yet but given the consistency in the documentation across the other apps could you not do something like this:

CalenderApp Script -> OnSumbit function -> if(title of calendar contains matching text 《I.e. Appointment》get the Id of the calender , get the user submit email -> Create a new google Form code with the questions you seek then call GmailApp to send the form to the UserEmail.

The form data could link to a spreadscript and you could add a script to the spreadsheet that on form submit it send info to a google doc for presentation purposes

Comment: Furthermore you could add more script to the spreadsheet that once the google doc is created it turns it into a pdf and emails it to the client as a confirmation. The form data could also go into the body text of the calender event

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri It's possible if you can effectively leverage push notifications. However, it's not exactly the most trivial thing to implement. See link: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push